# What is Eclipse doing when it says that it's updating indexes?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, m2e

When I load up a workspace (for Android Java development), Eclipse says in the status bar that it's updating indexes.  The Progress tab reports that it's hitting maven.org.

I read up on Maven - seems like a build manager.  What I don't understand is why my Android workspace needs it or why it's hitting the server in the cloud.  Do I need it?  If not, how do I safely remove it?

[image]

Comment: Is this workspace under version control?

Comment: @user384706 It is, via the Vault for Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is a general step that happens when m2e/m2eclipse (Maven integration for Eclipse) is installed, whether projects are actively using it or not.

This step can be disabled through the Eclipse preferences:  Window / Preferences / Maven / "Download repository index updates on startup".  This option is on the main "Maven" preference page (not a child page).  Just uncheck the box to prevent this from happening.

[image: Eclipse m2e Disable repository index updates on startup]

The file that this is downloading is an index of all the available dependencies available in the Maven central repository for use in Maven-enabled projects, allowing them to be easily chosen and searched against within the Eclipse UI.  It is mainly a user convenience, and isn't mandatory.

Comment: But why it takes bloody ages while this thread runs with high priority? iostat shows it takes up to 80% of IO and CPU bandwidth and brining performance of my machine to its knees. It seems to perform java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes().

Comment: Eclipse is a mine field, every feature comes with a load of bugs and caveats, the simple idea of running repository indexing on the same thread serving UI request is completely unacceptable

Comment: @PierluigiVernetto No, this does not run on the UI thread.  This process can be stopped, or disabled (referencing the posted screenshot).  The Maven central repository is huge - and maintaining a local index is a rather significant process.  End-users can decide whether this maintenance cost is worth the benefit / user convenience for easily searching and choosing artifact IDs from the Maven central repository.  (On my systems, I don't even notice a performance impact from the updates.)