# How to close this process on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I open my SpringIDE.It always have a process running!It display 'Indexing Jar Types',It looks maybe takes much CPU space,I want to close it but warried about if it will cause any problem?
Please help me.

Comment: Let it run to completion?

Answer (score 0):

Possible bug with STS. See [here](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4333)

You can also try disabling through the Eclipse preferences: Window / Preferences / Maven / "Download repository index updates on startup"

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647769/what-is-eclipse-doing-when-it-says-that-its-updating-indexes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514814/stopping-maven-index-update-eclipse)